# "closable : true" not showing close icon on top of the panel ( sencha touch 2.4)

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Below is my code which showing panel as a popup  , I am able to see video but i am not getting close icon on the top of the panel.
As we are providing  "closable : true" ,close icon should appear on the top.

```
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            width: '500px',
            left: '5%',
            padding: 10,
            top: '0%',
            title: 'Foo',
            floating: true,
            closable : true,
            layout: 'fit',
            height: '380px',
            html: ['<iframe frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" width = "480" height = "360" src = ""></iframe>']
    }));
```

Below is fiddler link

> fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1trn

Comment: Can you please create on fiddler for this. It is working fine for me in this fiddler. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1trl

Comment: I tried your code in fiddle with Ext 5.1.3 version and it seems to be working fine. Also its working on my end in Ext 6.0.2. Can you provide a fiddle recreating the issue?

Comment: @Harshit :I am using Sencha touch 2.4 , and I am showing this Panel from my controller.

Comment: Now i did it from my controller and just changed url with some string as i dont have url. Still its working.

Comment: Yes please create some fiddle kalashir.There you can select sencha versions.

Comment: @HarshitShah
Below is fiddle link
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1trn

Comment: Your title is misleading. Its not ext 5.4 it should be sencha touch 2.4

Comment: @ankitchaudhary :This code is working fine on chrome but on firefox it is not opening video in iframe. Any specific reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha Touch Panel don't have any `closable` property like extjs.We need to create our own button to achieve it.

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
   Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            width: '500px',
            left: '5%',
            padding: 10,
            top: '0%',
            title: 'Foo',
            floating: true,
            closable : true,
            layout: 'fit',
            height: '380px',
            items:{
                xtype:'button',
                right:0,
                top:0,
                  ui: 'plain',
               iconCls:'delete',
               handler:function(button){
                   button.up().destroy();
               }
            },
            html: ['']
})
);

    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.2/resources/css/sencha-touch.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.2/sencha-touch-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: @HarshitShah
This code is working fine on chrome but on firefox it is not opening video in iframe. Any specific reason ?